# Extending Tiles with Wildcart Support

Tags: apache, tiles

Tiles configuration

```
<definition name="defaultLayout" template="/{1}/{2}/common/{4}/layouts/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/{1}/{2}/common/s/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
 <!-- Default Layout Defination over -->
<definition name="*/*/*/*/*/index" extends="defaultLayout">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/{1}/{2}/common/s/index.jsp" />
```

Problem is my `defaultLayout` definition was not replace with define wildcart in child definition. 
When I was hit URL from my browser like `http://localhost:8080/etisalat/wap/common/b/index.wfv` then 
**Error is**

```
HTTP Status 404 - /{1}/{2}/common/{4}/layouts/layout.jsp

type Status report

message /{1}/{2}/common/{4}/layouts/layout.jsp

description The requested resource (/{1}/{2}/common/{4}/layouts/layout.jsp) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard placeholders are not passed on to the inherited definition.

You would need to

```
<definition name="defaultLayout.*.*.*" template="/{1}/{2}/common/{3}/layouts/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/{1}/{2}/common/s/footer.jsp" />
</definition>


<definition name="*/*/*/*/*/index" extends="defaultLayout.{1}.{2}.{4}">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/{1}/{2}/common/s/index.jsp" />
    ...
```